# Virtuoso VECSL Error from DBpedia endpoint on SPARQL CONSTRUCT query

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, endpoint, virtuoso, construct

When I run this query:

```
CONSTRUCT {
    ?band a dbo:Band ;
          foaf:name ?name;
          dbp:website ?website ; 
          dbo:abstract ?abstract ;
          dbo:genre ?genre;
          dbo:image ?image;
          dbp:currentMembers ?member .
}
WHERE 
{
    ?band a umbel-rc:Band_MusicGroup;
          foaf:name ?name;
          dbo:bandMember ?member;
          foaf:homepage ?website;
          dbo:abstract ?abstract.
FILTER(lang(?abstract) = "en").
OPTIONAL{?band dbo:genre ?genre} .
OPTIONAL {?band dbo:thumbnail ?image}.
}
LIMIT 10000.
```

I have this error:

> Virtuoso VECSL Error VECSL: Internal error, ssl refd before set, please report query to support

Please.  Help Me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the trailing dot/period/`.` after your `LIMIT` clause, which is a syntax violation.

Remove that dot, and your query will work.

(You would get a better error with a space before that trailing dot, `LIMIT 10000 .`.  I've raised this to the Development team to be addressed.)